# What data type does dictsort produce in Ansible/Jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

#### Explanation

Assuming I have a dictionary `mydict` set to `{ "key1": "value1" }`:

- The result of `dictsort` filter (`mydict|dictsort`) in Ansible seems to be a list containing another list:

  ```
  [
      [
          "key1",
          "value1"
      ]
  ]
  ```
- However, when accessing the first element of this list directly in Jinja2 template `(mydict|dictsort)[0]`, it renders to a strangely looking:

  ```
  (u'key1', u'value1')
  ```
- Then, if I set a fact with the value of `(mydict|dictsort)`, it behaves like a regular list - accessing the first element with `[0]` results in:

  ```
  [
      "key1",
      "value1"
  ]
  ```

  Accessing its `[0]` element returns `key1`.
- But if I set a fact with the value of `(mydict|dictsort)[0]`, it behaves like a string - accessing `[0]` element returns the first character, i.e. `(`.
- On the other hand, if I access subelements directly, for example `(mydict|dictsort)[0][0]`, it behaves like a list, i.e. returns `key1`.

#### Questions

- What is `(u'key1', u'value1')`? What kind of object does `dictsort` produce?
- How to access the `dictsort` results in a consistent, reliable way?

---

Full playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    mydict:
      key1: value1
  tasks:   
    - name: show dict
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ mydict }}"

    - name: show mydict|dictsort
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ mydict|dictsort }}"

    - set_fact:
        mydict_dictsorted: "{{ mydict|dictsort }}"

    - name: show (mydict|dictsort)[0]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (mydict|dictsort)[0] }}"

    - name: show mydict_dictsorted[0]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict_dictsorted[0] }}"

    - name: show (mydict|dictsort|list)[0]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (mydict|dictsort|list)[0] }}"

    - name: show (mydict_dictsorted|list)[0]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (mydict_dictsorted|list)[0] }}"

    - set_fact:
        mydict_dictsorted_element: "{{ (mydict|dictsort)[0] }}"

    - name: mydict_dictsorted_element
      debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict_dictsorted_element }}"

    - name: mydict_dictsorted_element[0]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict_dictsorted_element[0] }}"

    - name: (mydict|dictsort)[0][0]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (mydict|dictsort)[0][0] }}"
```

Full transcript:

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************

TASK [show dict] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "key1": "value1"
    }
}

TASK [show mydict|dictsort] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "key1",
            "value1"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [show (mydict|dictsort)[0]] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "(u'key1', u'value1')"
}

TASK [show mydict_dictsorted[0]] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "key1",
        "value1"
    ]
}

TASK [show (mydict|dictsort|list)[0]] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "(u'key1', u'value1')"
}

TASK [show (mydict_dictsorted|list)[0]] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "key1",
        "value1"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [mydict_dictsorted_element] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "(u'key1', u'value1')"
}

TASK [mydict_dictsorted_element[0]] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "("
}

TASK [(mydict|dictsort)[0][0]] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "key1"
```

<sub>I checked the values with `copy`/`content` and they are the same as `debug`'s (except indentation), so posting `debug` results for clarity.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dictsort` produces a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). It uses [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) under the hood.

So when you access it as `(mydict|dictsort)[0]`, you access Python's tuple.
Whereas if you access it after it is templated, you get generic list, because JSON doesn't make difference between tuples and lists, it has only lists.

**Update**: how to test – insert `print` into _dump_results [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/21cdddce744c56b0a1f844297b3e04b4467b8d64/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.py#L107), like this:

```
    print("Unaltered: {}".format(abridged_result))
    return json.dumps(abridged_result, indent=indent, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=sort_keys)
```

And see this as the output:

```
TASK [show mydict|dictsort] ***************************
Unaltered: {'msg': [(u'key1', u'value1')]}
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "key1",
            "value1"
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Update2**: why list of tuples becomes list of lists, but single tuple becomes string repr?

This is because of the fact that Jinja2 expression inside `{{...}}` can produce only string as its output, and there's some Ansible [template magic](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/690a626d0da92624235d6ef75f64c860b21b82ba/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py#L458) done to try to type-cast it back to some complex type. But this magic only works with strings that looks like `dicts` or `lists` and not `tuples`. So if you have dict with tuples inside or list of tuples, you'll get it evaluated, but if you have a single tuple, it will remain a string. Here's demo of this:

```
- name: results in a string
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test_str }}"
  vars:
    test_str: "(u'a', u'b')"

- name: results in a list of tuples/lists
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test_str }}"
  vars:
    test_str: "[(u'a', u'b')]"
```

Output:

```
TASK [results in a string] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "(u'a', u'b')"
}

TASK [results in a list of tuples/lists] ****************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "a",
            "b"
        ]
    ]
```

}

Comment: Although I understand, I'm not sure if this explanation makes logical sense. Particularly "*because JSON doesn't make difference between tuples and lists, it has only lists*" does not explain why accessing `(mydict|dictsort)[0]` produces a string containing a Python representation of a tuple, but accessing `(mydict|dictsort)` produces a string containing a JSON representation of a list of lists. JSON, if I understand correctly, is significant for rendering input (that's why with tuple it defaults to a string), but in producing `[ [ ] [ ] ]` from `(mydict|dictsort)` JSON is not involved, is it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show some insights of JSON usage.

Comment: Ok, so there is a JSON library involved on output. But the unaltered output just confirms that while `[ ( ) ]` gets converted to `[ [ ] ]`, bare `( )` remains `( )`. The behaviour doesn't look consistent. If "*JSON doesn't make difference between tuples and lists*" then why is `( )` not rendered as `[ ]`?

Comment: I've added another update to my answer about why single tuple results in a string.

Comment: Ok, so is the following statement correct? A logic to interpret tuples as lists exists in the code (directly or indirectly), but this part of the code is just not triggered for the strings starting with `(`.

Comment: Hmm. Tuples are displayed as lists because of JSON conversion – this is always true. But single tuple can't survive `{{...}}` because of the said rule (it remains string repr).

Comment: And JSON conversion is triggered on `{` or `[`. That's what I meant lately. So my first comment was an "attribution of the blame"-problem. My expectation was `( )` should also be converted to `[ ]`, thus I rendered "because" in your answer as pointing to the obstacle, while it's the other way around.[